# Regex to match a minimum of 1 special character

Tags: regex

I have the following regex that requires 1 number, 1 letter upper and 1 letter lower (w/ a minimum of 8 length)

```
Regex.IsMatch(password, "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$")
```

I need to add another filter to ensure one of the following special characters is present (any help?)

```
#, $, @, !, %, &, * ?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple!:

> Regex.IsMatch(Password,"[#$@!%&*?]");

Answer (score 2):

How about this?  `[#$@!%&*?]`

Answer (score 2):

Regex.IsMatch(password, "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])**(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])**.{8,}$")